# assigns_to doesn't work for Rails 3 Shoulda on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, shoulda

I'm using Rails3 with rspec and shoulda. I have the below spec

```
describe PagesController, "on GET to show while logged off" do
  before(:each) do
    @site = Factory.create(:site)
    @site.domains << Factory.create(:domain)
    @site.save!
    @site.pages << Factory.create(:page)
    @site.menus << Factory.create(:menu, {:site=>@site, :is_visible=>true})
    @site.menus << Factory.create(:menu, {:site=>@site, :is_visible=>true})
    @site.menus << Factory.create(:menu, {:is_visible=>false, :site=>@site})

    get :show
  end

  it { should render_template(:show) }
  it { should render_template('layouts/2col') }
  it { should assign_to(:site) }
  it { should assign_to(:site).with(@site) }
  it { should assign_to(:site).with(@site) }
  it { should assign_to(:page).with(@site.pages[0])}
  it "show visible menu_items only" do 
    assert assigns[:menu_items].length == 2
  end
end
```

Here's my Gem File

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'autotest'
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem 'rspec', '>=2.0.0.beta.19'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '>=2.0.0.beta.17'
  gem 'shoulda'
end
```

and here's my spec_helper

```
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'shoulda'
require 'shoulda/integrations/rspec2'
require 'authlogic/test_case'
require 'factory_girl
```

Ok so far everything pretty close matches what I've seen before, however whenever I run my tests I get the errors like below

```
1) PagesController on GET to show while logged off 
     Failure/Error: it { should assign_to(:site) }
     Expected action to assign a value for @site
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:19
```

No my first thought was that the code was broken, however the application runs correcty. Also if I test that the values are assigned by using the assigns[:site] then the test passes.

Has anyone any idea what I need to change in order to make these tests start working again.

Thanks In Advance

Andy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `subject { controller }` before your `it` statements. This actually confused me so badly for a while that I wrote [my first ever blog post about it](http://rspeicher.tumblr.com/post/1111927237/an-rspec2-shoulda-controller-gotcha).

Comment: nice one, amazingly the rspec shoulda documentation is really weak, compared to the test unit version. Its's taken me nights to figure this out, as the same code worked on Rails 2.

Comment: I can't get it working even specifying subject, my shoulda-matchers is (1.0.0.beta1) with rspec 2.4.0

Comment: Okay, for me this turned out to be because I was using refinery which injects a before filter into the application controller which was hijacking the 'get' before it even reached my action.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ruby 1.9.2 the `assign_to` matcher with the `shoulda-matchers` gem version lower than 1.0.0beta2 will still not work, even if you include the `subject { controller }` (which, I believe, is not really needed).

It's caused by a change in Ruby 1.9.2. Here is the [bugreport for shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda/issues/155/). The fix is [already included](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/commit/76a8aa726ecc5abdff86f4654ea0b3c438f43b6f) and released in `shoulda-matchers` version **1.0.0beta2**.

So just have this in your `Gemfile`:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  ...
```

and update to the latest version (1.0.0.beta2 atm):

```
bundle update shoulda-matchers
```